# Can I simulate a button press on a web page from terminal

Tags: command-line

I found that we can read gmail messages from a terminal window by using

```
curl
curl -u user --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"
```

I would now like to submit some text (from a textarea + button press) from terminal. So what are the steps to identify the action triggered when a button is pressed and how to simulate the same actions in terminal ?

For example, I want to simulate 'pass data' & 'button press' (submit ) of http://tokira.net/unicode/index.php

Comment: The first answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request should do what you want. You can find the param names for the `<form>` in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need something more complex than just submitting a post request (which can easily be done by cURL directly), you may want to check [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_rdoc.html), a ruby library for interacting with web pages.

Comment: Interesting. Have a look

Comment: A bit hard to setup in slow network, But do well

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lynx`:

```
lynx http://tokira.net/unicode/index.php
```

By default `lynx` is not installed in Ubuntu, but you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install lynx
```